# Unmarshell XML to Java Object

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, jax-rs

The below is the XML structure my REST service suppose to consume. I am using JAX-RS to create the services. I am not able to achieve this.

I tried many things. Right now there are two problems i am facing.
1) I am not able to map this xml to a java class, when there is namespace involved in the request.
2) Getting null when there is more than one root tags, (Invoke_Service, part, GData). if there is only part tag, then its working.

Can anyone please help me here. Direct me to the right documentation or example. Help me understand this.

```
<Invoke_Service>
 <part xmlns="http://www.examplone.com" name="param">
    <GData xmlns:oracle-xls-mapper="http://www.oracle.com/xsl/mapper/schemas"
           xmlns:aia-xls-mapper="http://www.oracle.com/xsl/Transform/java"
           xmlns:impl="http://exampletwo.com" xmlns="http://exampletwo.com">
        <impl:sProduct>
           <impl:productName>Machine</impl:productName>
           <impl:Customer>
              <item>
                 <impl:cus_name>James</impl:cus_name>   
                 <impl:cus_age>22</impl:cus_age>
              </item>
               <item>
                 <impl:cus_name>Johnny</impl:cus_name>   
                 <impl:cus_age>25</impl:cus_age>
              </item>
           </impl:Customer>
        </impl:sProduct>
       <impl:sProduct>
           <impl:productName>Machine2</impl:productName>
           <impl:Customer>
              <item>
                 <impl:cus_name>Dianna</impl:cus_name>   
                 <impl:cus_age>29</impl:cus_age>
              </item>
               <item>
                 <impl:cus_name>Daisy</impl:cus_name>   
                 <impl:cus_age>40</impl:cus_age>
              </item>
           </impl:Customer>
        </impl:sProduct>
       <impl:sProduct>
           <impl:productName>Machine3</impl:productName>
           <impl:Customer>
              <item>
                 <impl:cus_name>Sam</impl:cus_name>   
                 <impl:cus_age>50</impl:cus_age>
              </item>
               <item>
                 <impl:cus_name>Rocky</impl:cus_name>   
                 <impl:cus_age>30</impl:cus_age>
              </item>
           </impl:Customer>
        </impl:sProduct>
    </GData>
 </part>
</Invoke_Service>
```

I appreciate all the help i can get.

Comment: What do you mean by `Getting null when there is more than one root tags`? There is only one root tag and it is `Invoke_Service` in your case. Do you need to handle many different `XML` payloads?

Comment: @MichałZiober what i meant was, i need to map the sProduct to Product class. Which is not happening when there are more than one tag above it. I tried with removing all the tags except one tag before the sProduct, its working. Also had to remove the namespace prefix. Is it possible to map this payload to a java class using jaxb in jax-rs? Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Declarative Stream Mapping (DSM)](https://mfatihercik.github.io/dsm) stream parsing library to easly convert complex xml to java class.

First of all you must define mapping between xml data and your class fields in yaml format.

Here is mapping definitions for your xml. I suppose you want to getting list of product.

DSM ignore namespaces.

```
result:     
   type: array
   path: /.+GData/sProduct  # path is regex. you don't need to define all path.
   fields:
     productName: 
        path: productName  # DSM ignore namespace
     customers:
        type: array
        path: Customer/item
        fields: 
          name: 
            path: cus_name
          age: 
            path: cus_age
```

POJO class that you want to deserialize:

```
public class Product {
    public String productName;
    public List<Customer> customers;



    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Product [productName=" + productName + ", customers=" + customers + "]";
    }



    public static class Customer{
        public String name; 
        public int age;
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Customer [name=" + name + ", age=" + age + "]";
        } 


    }

}
```

Java Code to parse XML:

```
DSM dsm=new DSMBuilder(new File("path/to/mapping.yaml")).setType(DSMBuilder.TYPE.XML).create(Product.class);
List<Product> itemList =  (List<Product>>)dsm.toObject(xmlFileContent);
System.out.println(object);
```

Here is output:

```
[Product [productName=Machine, customers=[Customer [name=James, age=22], Customer [name=Johnny, age=25]]], Product [productName=Machine2, customers=[Customer [name=Dianna, age=29], Customer [name=Daisy, age=40]]], Product [productName=Machine3, customers=[Customer [name=Sam, age=50], Customer [name=Rocky, age=30]]]]
```

Comment: This is very helpful. But is it not possible to unmarshell this xml using jaxb and xml annotations?!

Comment: I am not fun of jaxb. Maybe it's possible but it will need to much configuration.  İf you have xsd you can generate jaxb classes it will be easier than writing all classes and annotations by hand

Comment: hmm. Actually i have a wsdl file for the same. Will that be helpful?. Xml is soo complex. Json is simple.

Comment: İf you have wsdl you can use wsimport tool to generate java class.  You can search for wsimport on Google.